# Can't get color detection on OpenCV to work(Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to follow along to some tutorials for making python play Tetris automatically, but I just can't get it to work. I'm following along to "https://pysource.com/2019/12/07/detect-tetris-board-and-tetrominoes-python-plays-tetris-p-3/" mainly, but have been looking elsewhere for win32gui alternatives, like "https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/04/opencv-python-color-detection/".

when I try to run the code:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--tetris.png")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["tetris.png"])

boundaries = [([164, 120, 104])]
boundaries1 = [([166, 122, 106])]

for (boundaries) in boundaries:
    lower = np.array(boundaries, dtype = "uint8")
    upper = np.array(boundaries1, dtype = "uint8")

    mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)

    cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([image, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I get this error message and I have no idea where it comes from:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-my.user-\Desktop\detection.py", line 18, in <module>
    mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-cff9bdsm\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:1743: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ! _src.empty() in function 'cv::inRange'
```

I'm trying to do color detection on the Tetris board, but I can't find any good alternative, can someone please tell me how to do/how I fix the error?

Comment: Check with a print() statement if you read the image correctly.

Answer (score 0):

your code is wrong. Try in this way:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2



image = cv2.imread("Untitled-1.jpg")

boundaries = (164, 120, 104)
boundaries1 = (166, 122, 106)

for (boundaries) in boundaries:
    lower = np.array(boundaries, dtype = "uint8")
    upper = np.array(boundaries1, dtype = "uint8")

    mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)

    cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([image, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```